# Elementor forms Multiple select not responsive on desktop

Tags: elementor

I created drop down lists using the type **select** on Elementor forms. I want users to select to be able to select multiple choices or items on the drop down lists so I enabled the **Multiple selection** button. When I check the form using my mobile phone [Mobile phone image / screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjA8k.jpg) it functions the way its supposed to but it doesn’t on the desktop [Desktop image / screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQsk6.jpg).

1. I have tried getting the latest version of the elementor pro plugin.
2. I have tried changing the length of words in the fields to various sizes.
3. I have rebuilding the form multiple times.